# Is this rim safe?

Tags: tire, safety, rims, damage

The rim has a parting at the join:

[image]

This is a brand new wheel, and I was wondering if this is a safe one. Could it split at the join?

Comment: The problem I would be worried about it with the brakes. If you have rim friction brakes (V-brakes, cantilevers, etc.) you might have issues with that gap. If you have disc brakes or similar to where you are not relying on your rims to brake, you should be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The joint is spanned by a spline (or two), glued or swaged into notches formed into the aluminum extrusion.  It is the integrity of the spline and the fastening mechanism that is the issue.  If the spline is cracked, obviously that's serious problem.  Also, if the fastening mechanism has failed to the extent that there's motion between spline and extrusion, that's a problem (though not as immediate a problem as a cracked spline).

The gap, by itself, is not a problem, so long as it's not the result of spline failure, and so long as it's not a gap for the full depth of the joint.  You want the joint to be tight near the outer circumference where the stress will be, and likely the rim manufacturers slightly tweak the joint so that it's more likely to gap at the inner circumference, especially on "deep" rims where getting an exact joint is more difficult.

In your picture it's hard to tell how "deep" the rim is, and whether the gap continues up to the outer circumference, so one can't make a very definitive statement.

Comment: Yeah I think it should be fine it's a 40mm deep rim and just looks as cheap as it was

Answer (score 4):

Send that wheel back where it came from.

I can't see enough to have a better answer, but if your wheel has gaps in it then I wouldn't ride no matter who made it and how.

Comment: Disagree, not enough to downvote. See Daniel's answer.

Comment: Its a brand new wheel, why not send it back?